# Disable activity from another activity?

Tags: android

I am using the following code to remove my app from the launcher:

```
if (!dialercode.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                            getComponentName(),
                            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
                }
```

However, that also stops that activity being launched through other means (secret code).

So, I have setup a separate Launcher activity that will be disabled instead (all the Launcher activity does is launch the main activity).

However, I don't know how to go about disabling the Launcher.java activity via the main activity - IE how do I get the component name for the Launcher activity when I'm in a different activity?

Comment: In the end, do you want an `Activity` to appear in the launcher at any given moment?

Comment: Yes, when it is first installed, so it can be opened so the secret code broadcast receiver will work, but I found a solution which I will post now :)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution, instead of using `getComponentName()` use:

`new ComponentName(context, Activity.class)` where Activity is the name of the Activity you wish to disable. You can use this in any activity in your application.